# Definition of operation of matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let V and w be finite-dimensional vector spaces with ordered bases $\beta={v_1,v_2,...,v_n}$ and $\gamma={w_1,w_2,...,w_m}$. Let $T:V \rightarrow$ be linear. Then for each j, $1 \leq j \leq n$, there exist unique scalars $a_{ij} \in F$, $1 \leq I \leq m$, such that $T(v_j)= \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}w_i$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$.

I don't get the operation of this one. $T(v_j)= \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}w_i$ Are we looking for the $j^{th}$ column of $w_j$?

Expanding, get $T(v_j)$=$a_{1j}w_1 + a_{2j}w_2+...+a_{mj}w_m$. I specifically don't understand the matrix operation here.

Comment: I don't think the problem is corrected stated here. Whether or not $T$ is linear, there always exist unique such scalars $a_{ij}$ since $w_1, \ldots, w_m$ is a basis of $W$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not properly stated. Since for any transformation $T:V\to W$ (whether or not it's linear), there are uniquely determined coefficients $a_{i,j}\in\mathcal{F}$ such that
\begin{equation}
T(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij} w_i
\end{equation}
by the *definition of basis*.

I think a right problem can be the one below.

> Let $V$ and $W$ be a finite-dimensional vector spaces with bases $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ respectively. Now let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation. Then prove that there exists $\newcommand{\reals}{{\mathbf R}}A\in\mathcal{F}^{m \times n}$ such that for any $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathcal{F}$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_m\in\mathcal{F}$ that satisfies
>   \begin{equation}
> T(x_1 v_1 + \cdots + x_n v_n) = y_1 w_1 + \cdots + y_m w_m,
> \end{equation}
>   it is satisfied that $y = Ax$.
>   Prove also that this matrix $A\in\mathcal{F}^{m\times n}$ is uniquely determined!

Note that if $V\in\reals^n$, $W\in\reals^m$, and $v_j$s and $w_i$s are the standard unit vectors, $A\in\reals^{m\times n}$ is nothing but *the* matrix which defines the usual linear transformation!

Answer (score 2):

I think I know where you're confused. However...

When a vector space is defined in an abstract way as this, you cannot say $j$th column without constructing specific coordinate system.

So since $T:V\to W$, $T(v_j)$ refers to some vector in $W$, i.e., $T(v_j)\in W$. And $\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij} w_i \in W$ is defined by the vector addition and scalar-multiplication.

However, if it helps you understand the abstract vector space, you can definitely think of $V$ and $W$ as subspaces of $\newcommand{\reals}{{\mathbf R}}\reals^p$ for some $p$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Can you explain the operation $\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij} w_i \in W$? It looks to me that $w_i$ doesn't fit the matrix $ a_{ij}$ properly in terms of matrix multiplication. That's the part I want to ask about.

Comment: @Twilight Ah! $a_{ij}$ is a scalar! So $\sum_i a_{ij} w_i$ is nothing but a linear combination of $w_i$s. Is this what you asked?

Comment: I see, I always thought this is done like matrix operation. Where the row of $a_{ij}$ has to multiply the column of $w_{I}$.

Comment: @Twilight Glad to see that now you understand it better. However, like I said in a comment to the original post, I don't think the problem is properly posed. I'll post another answer with my thought.

Comment: Thank you so much! But that was copied from the original text.

Comment: @Twilight No problem. I wrote a question which (I think) should be the right problem. Hope this can help you!

Comment: that definitely helps! Thx a lot!

Comment: @Twilight My Pleasure! :)